# Cloudera Hive on Spark 2.x?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, cloudera

Looking at this:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/latest/topics/spark2_known_issues.html#hive_on_spark

To summarize, it says Hive doesn't work on Spark 2.x in Cloudera.

However, I assume Hive does run on Spark 2.x in other distributions.  Has anyone configured CDH 5.10.x or higher to run Hive on Spark 2.x?

Is Spark 2.x a big leap forward from Spark 1.6?

Comment: Yes, Spark 2.x _is_ a big leap forward from Spark 1.6. I have not used Hive with Spark 2.x on my cloudera deployments, but I would encourage you to ask on the Cloudera user forums as well and respond here.

Comment: Not sure, but my understanding of this is the following: Hive-On-Spark 2 is the concept of using Spark 2 as the execution engine of Hive. Even without Hive-On-Spark 2, you can use Spark 2 and work with Hive tables (we do this using CDH 5.8 and this works fine)

Comment: So you mean you access the hive metadata, and then write custom spark jobs using it and the underlying data it's describing?  I suppose that could be useful, but we'd prefer to just be able to run Hive queries using Spark 2.x as the exe engine.  We can do this with Spark 1.6 on Cloudera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest released version of Hive as of now is 2.1.x and it does not support Spark 2.x (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14029). When Hive version [2.2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/HIVE/versions/12335837) is released it will support Spark 2.x.

Comment: Hive 2.3.0 is available now, which supports Spark 2.0 - http://www-us.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-2.3.0/