# HiveOnSpark for Cloudera Manager 5.15 or 6.0?

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager, spark-hive

It seems that HiveOnSpark is not supported in Cloudera Manager.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/latest/topics/spark2_known_issues.html#ki_hive_on_spark

Although I noticed someone saying that Hive version 2.2.0 does support Spark 2.x.

Can we really use Hive on Spark? (link below)

[Cloudera Hive on Spark 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749354/cloudera-hive-on-spark-2-x)

Answer (score 1):

If you want Spark2 then it's currently not supported.  Based on the CDH6.0.0 packaging info, it's using Hive 2.1.1 which is only compatible with Spark 1.6.  If you are fine with using Spark 1.6 then it is.  See [Running Apache Hive on Spark in CDH](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/admin_hos_oview.html) for more information.

The version compatability can be found at [Hive on Spark: Getting Started](https://cwiki-test.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started).

[image]